# (Selenium WebDriver) Не проверяет загружена ли страница

Tags: javascript, selenium

Есть тест:

1. Заходим на сайт blog.noveogroup.ru
2. Вбиваем в поиск webdriver
3. Ждём, пока страница не загрузится и не распознаем заголовок первого блока, название которого имеет значение 'Автоматизация QA: когда и зачем'

На третьем этапе ничего не выходит. В чем ошибка?

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example(){
  const driver = await new Builder()
  .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build()

  try{
    await driver.get('https://blog.noveogroup.ru/')
    await driver.findElement(By.css('[type=search]')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN)
    await driver.wait(until.driver.findElement(By.className('.post-list-unit__title')).text != 'Автоматизация QA: когда и зачем', 1000)
  } catch {
    console.log('FAILED')
  } finally {
    await driver.quit()
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Что значит ничего не выходит? Судя по коду третий шаг ожидает пока текст элемента не будет равен 'Автоматизация QA: когда и зачем' и, вероятнее всего, не дожидается и выбрасывается timeout exception

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).